# WATIR: "on(LoginPage).login_btn.exists?" failed to help in verifying/assesrting the element on page

Tags: watir

It's WATIR beginners problem:

I want to verify the "login button" on "Login Page". Using `pagefactory` I am able click on the button like this:

`on(LoginPage).login_btn` but can't verify using `on(LoginPage).login_btn.exists?` I've also tried `(on(LoginPage).login_btn).exists?`

Comment: I can see two possible problems. Either (1) the existence is not being checked in an actual assertion or (2) the method is being called incorrectly - eg I would have thought a `on(LoginPage).login_btn?` or `on(LoginPage).login_btn_element.exists?`

Comment: @JustinKo `on(LoginPage).login_btn?` and `on(LoginPage).login_btn_element.exists?` both works for me. Then what was the problem with what I was trying.